# Serving static files with C++

Tags: c++, static-files

I have own Web server implementation based on C++ TCP sockets. Now this server can send plain text in HTTP body. I need this server to send static files (HTML, CSS, JS). Files are located in `./static/` directory (`./static/admin.html`, `./static/admin.css`, `./static/admin.js`), server reads files contents and sends it to client with appropriate HTTP-headers. `admin.html` file has link to `admin.css` and `admin.js`, like it shown in the code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Admin Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="admin.js"></script>
    <!-- ... -->
</body>
</html>
```

1) How could client receive `css` and `js` files?

2) What is the common sense to serving static files?

2.1) Should I read `*.html` file to buffer, inject to the buffer contents of `*.css` in `<style>` tag and contents of `*.js` in `<script>` tag? Is there another more effective/elegant/good way?

Comment: You're already finished. The plain text files you send? Those are static files already. In the world of WWW and HTTP, a "static file" is simply a file that the server sends directly to the client without any processing.

Comment: Yes, that should be it. The browser will see the `<link>` and `<script>` tags and request the corresponding files independently.

Comment: You must have already tried to do the obvious, i.e. let the browser make separate requests for the extra resources. What didn't work?

Comment: As @Someprogrammerdude says this is almost finished! You just have to type the file sent back to client side which will be able to tackle it correctly. Add header, "Content-Type: text/html" for HTML files for example...

Comment: It's the *client* that should parse the contents of the files you send, not your server program. All you need to do to solve your problem is to send the correct mime-type header (as mentioned by @Jean-BaptisteYunès). You can do this very simply by mapping file-name suffix (like `.css`) to a mime-type (like `text/css`). This mapping is probably the only thing you need to change.

Comment: And on a disappointing note, once you're done then throw your current program away. There are many frameworks and libraries for handling *all* of this much better than your current home-made program will ever do. It's a good learning exercise, but for real-world applications please use some library or framework developed for it specifically.

Comment: Browser receives html with `<link>` and `<script>` tags and sends two requests for `css` and `js` file, right? So all I have to do is to implement these requests processing on server-side?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem which I summarized here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73649475/serving-static-files-in-uwebsockets-http-server-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. client will received .css and .js files but not the way you seem to think! When the client will request your html file it will parse it and will then find that it includes .css or .js, etc. So it will just ask for them separately in other requests. For this to work properly, you need to type the file sent back to client. Look for HTTP Header "Content-Type" (ex.: for HTML files you should type them as "Content-Type: text/html").
2. not clear what you are asking for.
3. certainly not, let the client do its job!

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers will did this for you, and all you need to do in server side is to response with correct files. Lol. Hope this will help you